# Как в Vue/Vuetify 2.x соединить v-data-table с динамическим v-autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Vue.js 2.x / Vuetify 2.x

Нужна динамическая таблица, чтобы на каждой строчке был v-autocomplete. Отслеживание ввода на нужной строке и аякс-запрос, на основании которого будут манипуляции с текущими данными таблицы.

[Пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kripto77/pen/QWbpXVg?editors=1011)

Проблема в отслеживании по полю :search-input.sync="searchText", при такой привязке вводимый запрос повторяется на всех v-autocomplete, если привязать по текущему итерационному элементу :search-input.sync="item.searchText" не получается отслеживать в watch: { searchText(value, oldValue) {} ) }

Подскажите как привязать к уникальной переменной и отследить изменения при вводе? 
Возможно как-то в watch отследить текущий итерационный объект (туда передаются только старое и новое значение, за исключением объектов с опцией deep: true)?

Очень прошу помочь, гугление не помогает, примеры или старых версий или с той же проблемой. Заранее спасибо.

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire">

    <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="tableItems"
            class="elevation-1"
    >
        <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
            <v-autocomplete
                    v-model="item.searchModel"
                    :items="items"
                    :loading="item.isLoading"
                    :search-input.sync="searchText"
                    color="black"
                    hide-selected
                    hide-no-data
                    item-text="Description"
                    item-value="API"
                    label="Search by Name"
                    :placeholder="item.name"
                    return-object
            ></v-autocomplete>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>

</v-app>
```

Vue

```
    
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
        descriptionLimit: 60,
        entries: [],
        isLoading: false,
        model: null,
        searchText: null,

        headers: [
            {text: 'Dessert name', align: 'start', value: 'name',},
            {text: 'Calories', value: 'calories'},
            {text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat'},
            {text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs'},
            {text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein'},
            {text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron'},
        ],
        tableItems: [
            {id: 1, searchText: null, searchModel: null, isLoading: false, name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, fat: 6.0, carbs: 24, protein: 4.0, iron: '1%',}, 
            {id: 2, searchText: null, searchModel: null, isLoading: false, name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9.0, carbs: 37, protein: 4.3, iron: '1%',},
            {id: 3, searchText: null, searchModel: null, isLoading: false, name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16.0, carbs: 23, protein: 6.0, iron: '7%',},
        ],
    }),


    watch: {
        searchText(val) {
          // Items have already been loaded
          if (this.items.length > 0) return


            if (!val || val === this.selectedName) {
                return
            }

            //this.clearEntries()
            this.isLoading = true
            this.fetchEntriesDebounced(val)
        },
    },

    computed: {
        // Срабатывает при вводе/изменении любого символа
        items() {
            let result = this.entries.map(entry => {
                const Description = entry.Description.length > this.descriptionLimit
                    ? entry.Description.slice(0, this.descriptionLimit) + '...'
                    : entry.Description

                return Object.assign({}, entry, {Description})
            })

            return result
        },
    },

    methods: {
        clearEntries() {
            this.count = 0
            this.entries = []
        },
        fetchEntriesDebounced(val) {
            clearTimeout(this._searchTimerId)
            this._searchTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
                this.fetchEntries(val)
            }, 2000) /* 1500ms throttle */
        },
        fetchEntries(val) {
            // Lazily load input items
            fetch('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    const {count, entries} = res
                    this.count = count
                    this.entries = entries
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
                .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
        },
    },

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему вот так:
Параметры передаваемые в компонент, запишите это:

```
        <v-autocomplete
               :items="items"
                :loading="item.isLoading"
                color="black"
                hide-selected
                hide-no-data
                item-text="Description"
                item-value="API"
                label="Search by Name"
                :placeholder="item.name"
                return-object
                @input.native="handlerInput($event)"
        ></v-autocomplete>
```

в методы добавьте это:

```
  handlerInput(event){
    this.searchText = event.target.value;
   }
```

С `vuetify` не работаю, поэтому, возможно, есть более правильное решение

Comment: Спасибо, правильное направление. Подробное решение https://jsfiddle.net/3jf8zhxm/1/